# Finding all subgroups of $\mathbb{Z_n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I can't use any theorems regarding cyclic groups or isomorphisms. A hint the exercise provides is: "If $f: G \to H$ is a surjective homomorphism and $N$ is a subgroup of $(G, *)$, then $f(N)$ is a subgroup of $(H, •)$. Consider the surjective homomorphism $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z_n}$". but I'm having a hard time using that. I'd appreciate any help.

**Update:** I'm almost certain that the following proposition solves my problem:

Let $K$ be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Then $K = \{\bar{0}, \overline{m}, \overline{2m}, \cdots,\overline{n-m} \}$, where $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m \mid n$.

I just have to prove it now, which is the current problem.

**Update 2:** I think I've managed to prove that the only subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ are those in the form of $x\mathbb{Z}_n =  \{\overline{wx} \ \vert \ \overline{w} \in \mathbb{Z}_n \} = \{\overline{0}, \overline{x}, \overline{2x}, \cdots, \overline{(n-1)x}\}$ , where $x \in \mathbb{N} $ is such t hat $x \mid n$. For this, I fist prove that any $x\mathbb{Z}_n$ with $x \mid n$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and after that I prove there are no subgroups not in that form. First, notice that $n = qx$ for some $q \in \mathbb{N}$. Trivially, $x\mathbb{Z}_n \subseteq \mathbb{Z}_n$ and $\overline{0} \in x\mathbb{Z}_n$ is its neutral element. Now I just need to take two elements $a, b$ in $x\mathbb{Z}_n$ and prove that $ab' \in x\mathbb{Z}_n$. For this, let $a = \overline{\alpha x}$ and $b = \overline{\beta x}$. Then $a - b = \overline{\alpha x} + \overline{n - \beta x} = \overline{(\alpha + q - \beta)x} \in x\mathbb{Z}_n $, and so $x\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z_n}$.

Now, let $K$ be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Let $k$ be the smallest positive integer such that $\overline{k} \in K$. By long division, we have that $n = pk + r$ for some $0\leq r < k$. Then $r = n - pk$, and since $K$ is a subgroup, it's trivial that $\overline{r} \in K$. Now, since $0 \leq r < k$ and $k$ is the smallest positive integer such that $\overline{k} \in K$, we have $r = 0$. Then $n =pk $ and $k \mid n$. Trivially, $k\mathbb{Z}_n \subseteq K$. Now, let $y = \overline{m} \in K$. By the exact same argument, $k\mid m$ and therefore $y = \overline{tk} \in k \mathbb{Z}_n$ for some $t \in \mathbb{N}$ and it follows that $K=k\mathbb{Z}_n$. Then we're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  Let $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Then $N = \langle k \rangle \leq \mathbb{Z}$ and $f(N) \leq \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

(Possibly helpful:

- We're using $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},+)$.
- $\langle k \rangle = \langle -k \rangle$.

)

Things to show/work out:

- Are there any subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ that are not $\langle k \rangle$ for some $k$?  (Any such subgroup is a subset which, since $\mathbb{Z}$ is well ordered, has a least positive element...)
- Does the fourth isomorphism/lattice isomorphism/correspondence theorem tell you that you have found all the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ by this method?
- What relationship between $k$ and $n$ forces $f(N)$ to be all of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?  Then what happens when that relationship does not hold?

Comment: What do you mean with the notation $\langle k \rangle$? Also, unfortunately I can't use any of the theorems you mentioned in this exercise nor mention cyclic groups.

Comment: First, you can mention one cyclic group, $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.  $\langle k \rangle$ is the subset generated by $k$.  In $\mathbb{Z}$, $\langle k \rangle$ is all the integer multiples of $k$.  You have been shown how to prove that you have all the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ *without* using any thoerems.  After using the fourth isomorphism theorem to tell *you* that you have all the subgroups, you have to convince *your reader* of the same, perhaps by using the same argument as for the first bullet.

Comment: I think I get what you're saying. I know $\langle k \rangle = k \mathbb{Z}$, and as for the first bullet, I know how to prove the only subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ are $n\mathbb{Z}$ with $n$ integer. As for the third bullet, I have worked out a few particular cases and my intuition tells me that if $n$ is prime, then $f(N)$ is all of $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$, but I'm not sure how to prove it or how that helps me classify all the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Comment: It could be instructive to set $n = 6$ and see what happens as you vary $k$.

Comment: I did that and it wasn't all that helpful. I managed to find the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_6$, but I wasn't able to find a deeper generalization to help me solve my problem. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: So how are $\{1,5\}$ different from $\{2,3,4\}$ modulo $6$?

Comment: Well, $1 \in \bar{1}$, $2 \in \bar{2}$ and so on (until $5 \in \bar{5}$ modulo $6$, of course) modulo $6$.

Comment: Okay ...  How are $\{1,5\}$ different from $\{2,3,4\}$ in the *ring* $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I don't know the difference other than that they belong to different classes. Sorry for the dumbness and thanks for the patience. I think I have figured out the answer to my question and I'll update my post with it (I just have to prove it now), that's likely to be more productive, so if you could help me with that it'd be great.

Comment: Really?  You have no idea what divisibility relation $1$ and $5$ have with $6$ that $2$, $3$, and $4$ *do not* have with $6$?

Comment: $1 \mod{6} = 5 \mod{6}$, whereas $2 = 2 \mod{6}$, $3 = 3 \mod{6}$ and $4 = 4 \mod{6}$. I think I've managed to solve the problem, could you please check my proof? I gotta thank you even if only for the patience you've had so far, but I'd really like to accept your answer and close this thread already (if my proof is correct, of course).

Comment: How do you *not* notice, given that you are considering divisibility, that $\gcd(1,6) = \gcd(5,6) = 1$, and $\gcd(2,6)$, $\gcd(3,6)$, $\gcd(4,6)$, and even $\gcd(6,6)$ are all greater than $1$?

Comment: It honestly did not occur to me. I can be dumb like that sometimes. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

A better hint is: the subgroups of $H$ are the images of the subgroups of $G$ that contain $\ker f$.

In your case, this leads to: Which subgroups of $\mathbb Z$ contain $n \mathbb Z$?

Comment: A subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ is always some $m\mathbb{Z}$. The subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ that contain $n\mathbb{Z}$ are $m\mathbb{Z}$ such that $m \vert n$. How does this help me, though?

Comment: @MatheusAndrade, you're right. So the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ are $m\mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z}$ for $m \mid n$.

Comment: What do you mean by the notation $m\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$? I'm somewhat familiar with the quotient group, but this is the first time I'm seeing something like this. Thanks for the help, I think I'm closer to solving it now.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. All I have to do now is prove the first hint...

Comment: @lhf  The image of the subgroups of $\Bbb Z$ containing $n\Bbb Z$ are actually the subgroups of $\Bbb Z_n$ , that we are looking for. So, the subgroups of $\Bbb Z_n$ are $[m\Bbb Z]$, $\forall m|n$, where $[m\Bbb Z]=\{[mn]|n\in\Bbb Z\}$, correct? Is that you want to mean ?