# Find all the subgroups of $\Bbb Z/21\Bbb Z$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation, group-isomorphism, cyclic-groups

Find all the subgroups of $\Bbb Z/21\Bbb Z$.

The solution given is as follows:

> Let $K$ be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/21\mathbb{Z}$. Then $K=H/21\mathbb Z$ for some subgroup
> $H$ of $\Bbb Z$ such that $21\Bbb Z\subset H$. Again, if $H$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z$, such that $21\Bbb Z\subseteq H$, then $H/21\Bbb Z$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z/21\Bbb Z$. So we have to determine all subgroups of $\Bbb Z$ that contains $21\Bbb Z$. Now, $1,3,7,21$ are the only positive divisors of $21$. Hence $\Bbb Z,3\Bbb Z,7\Bbb Z$ and $21\Bbb Z$ are the only subgroups of $\Bbb Z$ that contain $21\Bbb Z$. Then $\Bbb Z/21\Bbb Z$, $3\Bbb Z/21\Bbb Z$, $7\Bbb Z/21\Bbb Z$, and $21\Bbb Z/21\Bbb Z$ are the only subgroups of $\Bbb Z/21\Bbb Z$.

However, I don't get how do they conclude "Let $K$ be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/21\mathbb{Z}$.Then $K=H/21\mathbb Z$ for some subgroup
$H$ of $\Bbb Z$ such that $21\Bbb Z\subset H$"? Also, how do they say, "Again, if $H$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z$, such that $21\Bbb Z\subseteq H$, then $H/21\Bbb Z$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z/21\Bbb Z$."? I don't get this proof at all. Can anyone please help me with this?

The following link: [Finding all subgroups of $\mathbb{Z_n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2776707/finding-all-subgroups-of-mathbbz-n) does not answer my question as my post asks for explanation of a particular proof while in that post, the user asks for a proof of the problem .

Comment: @DietrichBurde Although, this question is closed. But I don’t get it? Are they related? Then how? I think I am missing something. If you kindly clarify I will be soo much grateful...

Comment: Lhf's answer at the duplicate is very helpful. You take $n=21$. Then the subgroups of $\Bbb Z/21\Bbb Z$ correspond to subgroups of $\Bbb Z$ containing $21\Bbb Z$. Then the comments at lhf's answer say how to proceed.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde I see it now. Thank you! Just I need a little verification which goes as follows: Finding all subsets of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ is equivalent to finding all subgroups of $\Bbb Z_n$ since  $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z=\Bbb Z_n$. Now, we use the lemma that if there exists a surjective homomorphism of the form $f:G\to H$, then for each subgroup of H there exists a subgroup $G$ containing $Kerf$ such that there is one-one correspondence between them. Now, we consider the epimorphism $f:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z_n$, and we know that if $f(n)=[n],\forall n\in\Bbb Z$, then it is a homomorphism.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Now, all the subgroups of $\Bbb Z_n$ has a one-one correspondence with subgroups of $\Bbb Z$ containing $Ker f=n\Bbb Z$  and hence we just need to find all the subgroups of $\mathbb Z$ containing $n\Bbb Z$ i.e we know any subgroup of $\Bbb Z$ is of the form $p\Bbb Z$ and if it has to contain $n\Bbb Z$, then $p|n$.Thus, we can say all the subgroups of $\Bbb Z_n$ has a one-one correspondance with $p\Bbb Z$ such that $p|n$. But I don’t get what are the subgroups of $\Bbb Z_n$ , explicitly? Am I missing something?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Ohh! Maybe , I missed an important part. The image of the subgroups of $\Bbb Z$ containing $n\Bbb Z$ are actually the subgroups of $\Bbb Z_n$ , that we are looking for. So, the subgroups of $\Bbb Z_n$ are $[m\Bbb Z]$, $\forall m|n$, where $[m\Bbb Z]=\{[mn]|n\in\Bbb Z\}$, correct?

Comment: Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be a group and $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$, consider the quotient group $G/N$.
You can prove, applying the [Correspondence theorem for groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theorem) to the projection $p_N:G \to G/N$, that the (normal) subgroups of $G/N$ are exactly those of the form $H/N$ where $H$ is a (normal) subgroup of $G$ containing $\ker p_N$ (note that $\ker p_N=N$).

Now, you can easily prove that $n\Bbb{Z} \subseteq m\Bbb{Z} $ if and only if $m |n$.

Hence, the subgroups of $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ are only exactly those of the form $m\Bbb{Z} / n\Bbb{Z}$ where $n\Bbb{Z} \subseteq m\Bbb{Z}$, namely $m|n$.